# python: comparing 2 lists of instances

Tags: python, list, class, search, instance

I have 2 lists of instances:

```
list1
list2
```

each instance contains variables such as id, name, etc...

I am iterating through list2, and I want to find entries that don't exist in list1.

eg..

```
for entry in list2:
  if entry.id in list1:
    <do something>
```

I'm hoping to find a way to do this without a douple for loop.  Is there an easy way?

Comment: What type are the instances?  Do they implement `__hash__`?

Comment: from the question i am assuming, you have a list of objects of a class in the 2 lists, and want to get a filtered list based on your condition

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I might do something like:

```
set1 = set((x.id,x.name,...) for x in list1)
difference = [ x for x in list2 if (x.id,x.name,...) not in set1 ]
```

where `...` is additional (hashable) attibutes of the instance -- You need to include enough of them to make it unique.

This takes your O(N*M) algorithm and turns it into an O(max(N,M)) algorithm.

Comment: thanks, this worked perfectly for me.  I only needed id in the end as this was already unique

Answer (score 9):

Just a thought...

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return '({},{})'.format(self.id, self.name)

list1 = [Foo(1,'a'),Foo(1,'b'),Foo(2,'b'),Foo(3,'c'),]
list2 = [Foo(1,'a'),Foo(2,'c'),Foo(2,'b'),Foo(4,'c'),]
```

So ordinarily this does not work:

```
print(set(list1)-set(list2))
# set([(1,b), (2,b), (3,c), (1,a)])
```

But you could teach `Foo` what it means for two instances to be equal:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self.id, self.name))

def __eq__(self, other):
    try:
        return (self.id, self.name) == (other.id, other.name)
    except AttributeError:
        return NotImplemented

Foo.__hash__ = __hash__
Foo.__eq__ = __eq__
```

And now:

```
print(set(list1)-set(list2))
# set([(3,c), (1,b)])
```

---

Of course, it is more likely that you can define `__hash__` and `__eq__` on `Foo` at class-definition time, instead of needing to monkey-patch it later:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '({},{})'.format(self.id, self.name)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.id, self.name))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            return (self.id, self.name) == (other.id, other.name)
        except AttributeError:
            return NotImplemented
```

---

And just to satisfy my own curiosity, here is a benchmark:

```
In [34]: list1 = [Foo(1,'a'),Foo(1,'b'),Foo(2,'b'),Foo(3,'c')]*10000

In [35]: list2 = [Foo(1,'a'),Foo(2,'c'),Foo(2,'b'),Foo(4,'c')]*10000
In [40]: %timeit set1 = set((x.id,x.name) for x in list1); [x for x in list2 if (x.id,x.name) not in set1 ]
100 loops, best of 3: 15.3 ms per loop

In [41]: %timeit set1 = set(list1); [x for x in list2 if x not in set1]
10 loops, best of 3: 33.2 ms per loop
```

So @mgilson's method is faster, though defining `__hash__` and `__eq__` in `Foo` leads to more readable code.

Comment: Note that you may want to be a little more careful about your hashing function.  try:  `a = Foo(1,'a'); set([a,hash(a)])` with cpython 2.7.3 and you'll get an attribute error since you can't compare `Foo` with `int` objects.

Comment: @mgilson: Thanks; I add some code (to `__eq__`) to address that possibility. Please tell me if you were thinking of something else or see an improvement.

Comment: I think that rather than raising a `TypeError`, it is pretty typical to just return `False`.  Objects of different types always compare unequal in python (unless you override `__eq__` to make it otherwise).  I think you're confusing `==` with other so-called rich comparisons (`>=`).  In python3, you can't use rich comparisons on objects of different types, but you **can** still use `==`.  Perhaps in this case raising `NotImplemented` would be OK as then it would fall back on the other's comparison which would say "No, this isn't right ..."

Comment: @mgilson: Oops! You are absolutely correct. Equality testing just returns `True` or `False` in both Python2 and Python3. I'll delete the useless blather. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter`

```
difference = filter(lambda x: x not in list1, list2)
```

In Python 2 it will return the list you want. In Python 3 it will return an`filter` object, which you might want to convert to a list.

Comment: No reason to avoid a list comprehension here -- `difference = [ x for x in list2 if x not in list1 ]`.  This has the advantage that it gives you the same thing on python3 and python2 -- but don't kid yourself, this is still just as much a "double for loop" as OP's original code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
In [1]: list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [2]: list2 = [4,5,6,7]

In [3]: final_list = [x for x in list1 if x not in list2]
```