# How to compare two list of dictionaries (JSON) in python and output only the changes between them?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I need to compare the following lists:

```
Old list:
[
    {
        "dns-a": [
            "107.180.51.238",
            "107.180.51.238"
        ],
        "dns-aaaa": [],
        "domain-name": "raz.com",
        "fuzzer": "original*"
    },
    {
        "dns-a": [
            "69.172.200.131",
            "69.172.200.131"
        ],
        "dns-aaaa": [],
        "domain-name": "raza.com",
        "fuzzer": "addition"
    },
]

New List:
[
    {
        "dns-a": [
            "107.180.51.238",
            "107.180.51.238"
        ],
        "dns-aaaa": [],
        "domain-name": "raz.com",
        "fuzzer": "original*"
    },
    {
        "dns-a": [
            "69.172.200.131",
            "69.172.200.131"
        ],
        "dns-aaaa": [],
        "domain-name": "raza.com",
        "fuzzer": "addition"
    },
    {
        "dns-a": [
            "104.224.184.187",
            "104.224.184.187"
        ],
        "dns-aaaa": [],
        "domain-name": "razb.com",
        "fuzzer": "addition"
    }
]

The output should be:
        {
            "dns-a": [
                "104.224.184.187",
                "104.224.184.187"
            ],
            "dns-aaaa": [],
            "domain-name": "razb.com",
            "fuzzer": "addition"
        }
```

I've tried the following:

```
def Diff(old_list, new_list): 
    list_dif = [i for i in old_list + new_list if i not in old_list or 
    i not in new_list]
    return list_dif
```

When the lists are the same I get back that nothing is different but if one thing is different I get back the entire list.

What are my options to do this right ?
I've looked on similar solutions but none of them worked for me.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? StackOveflow isn't a WriteForMe Code Editor. Please, share your work and the community will help you to reach your goal !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: comparing 2 lists of instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721062/python-comparing-2-lists-of-instances)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
difference = filter(lambda x: x not in old_list, new_list) + filter(lambda x: x not in new_list, old_list)
```

Comment: Thank you very much !
That was exactly what I was looking for